# How to add :hover to parent in sass?

Tags: css, sass

In sass, if I originally had

```
.a:hover {}
.a .b {}
.a .c {}
```

how can I factor out .a but keep the :hover, I tried

```
.a {
    :hover {}
    .b {}
    .c {}
}
```

but it doesn't work. Does anyone know how?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add "&" before ":hover"

```
.a {
    &:hover {}
    .b {}
    .c {}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
parent {
  &:hover {
    property
  }
}
```

results

```
parent:hover {
  property
}
```